# Como definir tamanho máximo de 2 textfields separadamente (Swift)

Tags: swift, validação, xcode

Seguinte, to iniciando agora com Swift e programação de iOS. Tenho uma duvida: como fazer a validação de 2 textFields diferentes?
Por exemplo, eu consegui com o código abaixo fazer a validação de 1 único campo, mas o problema que meu aplicativo tem 4 campos e essa validação esta contando os caracteres de todos os campos. Tipo, se o textField que eu coloquei ali no "return" atinge o maxCharCount, alem de travar este textField, ele trava todos os próximos também. Como fazer para ele validar cada campo separadamente?

```
func textField(_ shouldChangeCharactersIntextField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    return textField.text!.characters.count + string.characters.count <= self.maxCharCount

}
```

Ja tentei de varias formas: criar uma função para cada textField, juntar os 4 textfields dentro do return, encadeados de if, tudo o xcode reclama ou não funciona do jeito certo. Alguém ja passou por isso e saberia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Você pode diferenciar cada `UITextField`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var meuTextField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var meuTextField2: UITextField!    

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if  textField == meuTextField1 {
        // algoritmo aqui
        // return true|false
    }
    if  textField == meuTextField2 {
        // algoritmo aqui
        // return true|false
    }
    ...
}
```